# How to fix problem with Latex in R-Markdown?

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, pdflatex

I have an R Markdown issue, I am trying to write my thesis on it, when I run the code to generate the pdf, the following message is shown:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \counterwithout already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Error: Failed to compile THESIS.tex. See THESIS.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

**Any suggestion**?

Comment: Can you show the YAML header/preamble you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Found your error on [TeX exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425600/latex-error-command-counterwithout-already-defined), and the solution seems to be to define the following variables:

```
\let\counterwithout\relax
\let\counterwithin\relax
```

Before the package `chngcntr` (if you are using it).
(Credit to [the original answer post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle))